Good backup strategy for system and documents both on same drive?
I previously had two drives, one for Windows, one for documents, each with separate backups.
Upgrading to a single bigger drive containing both, i.e. documents will be in C:\Users.
I was wondering how I could still maintain separate backups for a unique drive.
The general idea:

make a 1st disk backup for Windows, excluding C:\Users\...\Documents, pictures, etc

this would automatically add any possible new system folders appearing in the disk


make a 2nd file backup for documents, pictures, etc, all in C:\Users

this one is very simple, it just backup a specified set of folders



Acronis can perform a disk backup, excluding specific folders:

Then comes things like AppData, as I understand, they're better off kept in the Windows backup?
By doing so, I would then be able to individually restore each backup independently.
Does that makes sense? Are there any other system folders I should consider?

It’s not really clear what your asking. You can’t simply backup system files. If you want a backup of system files you need an image of your system.

@Ramhound This is precisely why I mentioned a disk backup for system, it would backup the system with the added bonus that it can exclude specific folders (documents here). Does that make any sense?

@Ramhound I've updated my question to better reflect that it'd be a disk backup for the system, thus, a restore would theoretically work fine.

So why system files would you be interested? Backing up say page file.says would accomplish absolutely nothing. Every file in that screenshot should never be backedup

Have you noticed that these files are excluded from the backup??

My comment had a typo. I was asking what system files your interested in backing up.

There really is no reason to split this into 2 backups. Most backup solutions can partially restore from the backup anyway, including Acronis, where you can just open the tib file from a computer that has Acronis installed, and copy the files out.
As for not backing up the AppData folder, I strongly recommend that you DO backup the appdata folder. Especially the AppData\Roaming is going to be very interesting, as this is where you find things like your browser's bookmarks and what not.
While in general it is true that the AppData will be restored if you install the software again, AppData\Roaming usually contains settings that you'd like to keep. Although it is not going to be a huge problem to recreate, restoring this from backup is just going to be faster.
Do note that even if you backup every file, it is not always guaranteed that you can restore everything.
For example, if you backup Chrome entirely from both AppData\Local and AppData\Roaming, you go to a new computer, the new user has a slightly different username and you restore these, you will find out that the local password manager is actually empty. This is a security feature. In order for Chrome to backup passwords, you actually need to set a flag to enable export, and then export them first.
Note, this Chrome example may not be the only thing. Some programs may store their settings in the registry.
Anyway, my point is, a single backup is advised. The only reason why you would want to go for your solution, is that you have little storage space to backup to.
The biggest plus with Acronis system backup, is that it creates a full image, so you could essentially restore the entire image to the pc, and everything works. All registry settings are restored, and chrome's password manager will also work. But as added bonus, you can also choose to start fresh and extract files from that same backup.
You see, one backup, multiple options. Why create two backups and limit yourself?

No, you can partially restore, that's my entire take on it. So if you want to restore the system, but not documents (which you can't do, because a system restore deletes the partition entirely, and then restores the image) you would end up with a restore that has no documents at all. So if you first make a system backup before restoring the old one, then restore the old backup, you can then extract the documents from the newer system image.
